# Text Box Updating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update the userPoints text box with an array.

```
var points = new Array();    
points[0] = [10];
points[1] = [15];
points[2] = [5];
points[3] = [10];
points[4] = [15];
points[5] = [10];
points[6] = [15];
points[7] = [10];
points[8] = [15];
points[9] = [15];  

function rightOrWrongAnswer(){
    $("#choiceSelector > ol > li").click(function() {
        // for userChoice when they click, turn it into text
        var userChoice = $(this).text();

        // userChoice equals answers    
        if(userChoice == answers[count]){

            // change that answer to green
            $(this).css("color", "green");
```

I think this is the problem with this line below.

```
// update the points box
userPoints += points[0];
```

Or it could be when I am updating the the text box here

```
        $("#userPoints").val(points[count]);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you give a jsfiddle please

Comment: alright just a moment

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sneakmiggz/SL7bP/

Comment: here it is the jsfiddle

Comment: Where you have defined userpoints variable?

Comment: and what is in the answers array?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sneakmiggz/SL7bP/1/embedded/result/

Comment: userPoints variable is a global variable and in the answers array is the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `points` is an array of arrays you need to access it by index

```
// update the points box
userPoints += points[count][0];
$("#userPoints").val(points[count][0]);
$("#totalScore").val(userPoints);
```

Instead if you had defined `points` as follows your code would have worked

```
var points = [ 10, 15, 5, 10, 15, 10, 15, 10, 15, 15 ];
userPoints += points[count];
$("#userPoints").val(points[count]);
$("#totalScore").val(userPoints);
```

And after some boundary checking here is a working fiddle

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SL7bP/6/)

Answer (score 0):

move  following block from rightOrWrongAnswer()

```
// move to the next question in counter
            count++;
```

to

displayNextQuestion() {

http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/SL7bP/2/

The calculation points are not at right places check them again this was one example where your answer was moving to next questions answer. use alert for checking whats going on.

Comment: when i Do that, the questions get messed up, and the text box value, still doesn't update.